# batch rename file while keeping part rar number

Tags: batch-file, rename

Like the title suggests I want to batch rename files but keep the part of rar file.

Example:

- File-01.part1.rar
- File-01.part2.rar

Output:

- Newfile__01.part1.rar
- Newfile__01.part2.rar

Below is the rename part of the code.

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

REM Set your Year, Month, Day variable values here.
REM They will be used for file renaming.

CD "D:\test\rename"

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%A IN (`DIR "*.rar" /B /A:-D`) DO (
    REM Extract the last 2 chars of the file name.
    SET FileName=%%~nA
    SET First4=!FileName:~0,5!
    SET Last2=!FileName:~-2!

    REM Rename the file, inserting the new data.
    RENAME "%%A" "!First4!__!Last2!%%~xA"
)
ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example script based on my assumption of what you wanted to do:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Set "sd=D:\test\rename"
Set "xf=.rar"

If Not Exist "%sd%\*%xf%" Exit /B
CD /D "%sd%" 2>Nul || Exit /B

Set "ds="
For /F "Tokens=1-3 Delims=/ " %%A In ('RoboCopy/NJH /L "\|" Null'
) Do If Not Defined ds Set "ds=%%A%%B%%C"

For %%A In ("*%xf%") Do (Set "fn=%%~nA"
    For %%B In ("!fn!") Do (Set "fx=%%~xB"
        If /I Not "!fx:.part=!"=="%%~xB" Set "fn=%%~nB")
    Ren "%%A" "!fn:~,4!_%ds%_!fn:~-2!!fx!%xf%$")
Ren "*%xf%$" "*%xf%"
```

I have slotted the year, month, day variable, `%ds%` in between the two underscores, meaning:

- `File-01.part1.rar` would be renamed to `File_20180523_01.part1.rar`
- `Testing18.part2.rar` would be renamed to `Test_20180523_18.part2.rar`
- `Archive02.rar` would be renamed to `Arch_20180523_02.rar`.

Comment: what's if I want to add suffix, like `archive02.rar` to `archive02_suffixhere.rar`

Comment: A small hint for readers: The batch file as is does not work if a file name contains one or more exclamation marks because of enabled delayed expansion. This is a general problem on processing file names with a __FOR__ loop and using delayed expansion. But `!` in file names are rare and so this batch file makes a very good job.

Answer (score 0):

Try this batch file after modification of folder path in third line:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "Folder=D:\test\rename"

for /F "eol=| delims=" %%A in ('dir "%Folder%\File-01.part*.rar" /A-D-H /B /ON 2^>nul') do (
    for /F "eol=| delims=" %%B in ("%%~nA") do ECHO ren "%Folder%\%%A" "Newfile__01%%~xB%%~xA"
)

endlocal
pause
```

**Note:** The command **ECHO** is used here on line 6 to just demonstrate what would be the rename command line. Run the batch file as is for verification. When everything looks okay, remove **ECHO** and run the batch file once again to really rename the files.

This batch file runs **FOR** which runs the command **DIR** with using a separate command process started in background with `cmd.exe /C` to output

- just the names in bare format because of `/B`
- of only non hidden files because of `/A-D-H` (attribute not directory and not hidden)
- sorted by name because of `/ON`
- matching in specified folder the wildcard pattern `File-01.part*.rar`.

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background. `2>nul` redirects the error message output on no file matching the criteria from handle **STDERR** to device **NUL** to suppress it.

**FOR** captures the output of started command process and processes it line by line with ignoring empty lines.

The default end of line character `;` is modified with `eol=|` from semicolon to vertical bar. **FOR** ignores by default lines starting with a semicolon. A file name can start with a semicolon. But a file name can't contain a vertical bar.

**FOR** splits up by default a line on spaces/tabs and assigns just first part to specified loop variable `A`. The line splitting behavior is disabled by `delims=` which specifies an empty list of delimiters resulting in getting the file name with file extension but without file path as output by **DIR** assigned to the loop variable.

The inner **FOR** loop processes as string just the file name without file extension. This is the string from first character up to character before last dot, i.e. `File-01.part1` and `File-01.part2` and assigns this part to loop variable `B`. For the inner **FOR** the file extension is again everything after last dot which is `.part*`. The real file extension `.rar` of the file is unknown for the inner **FOR** loop processing just a file name string.

The command **REN** renames the current file referenced full path to new file name with keeping `.part*` referenced with `%%~B` from inner **FOR** loop and original file extension `.rar` from outer **FOR** loop.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `pause /?`
- `ren /?`
- `setlocal /?`